# Spring data jpa save can not get id

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My entity id is generated, and it was working fine when I use DAO instead of Spring data JPA.

```
@Id
@Column(name = TABLE_COLUM_NAME_ID)
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
```

Now I have starting to use Spring data JPA, and after I call `repository.save(myboject)`, or `repository.saveAndFlush(myobject)`, I call `myobject.getId()`. But the id is never populated.

I searched my database and the object is in the database and the id is correct. 
Does anyone know why the id is not set after i called `save()`? I have no issue when I use `entitymanager.save()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this like

```
myboject = repository.save(myboject);
repository.flush();
```

Then after call to `getId()`;

Comment: The problem is MyEntity requestEntity; savedEntity = repositroy.save(requestEntity).  Id is not in requestEntity but in savedEntity

Comment: @NPKR Please don't give answers like try this... add proper explanation to answer whenever needed.

Comment: No need for this, you just have to add the following annotations in the entity:
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

Answer (score 25):

I believe this post answers your question:

[Why to use returned instance after save() on Spring Data JPA Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625150/why-to-use-returned-instance-after-save-on-spring-data-jpa-repository)

The `repository.save()` method actually returns a new object like JPA `entityManager.merge()` and the returned object is the one that will have the ID set.

Answer (score 16):

1. You should use the `repository.saveAndFlush();` method:

> `MyObject savedObject= repository.saveAndFlush(newObject);`

2. In the Entity object description, you should add the following attribute(`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`) to the related field(`id`):

> ```
> @Id   
> @Column(name = "id")   
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)   
> public long getId() {  
>     return id;  
> }
> ```

Comment: this worked for me thanks, was missing the generateValue annotation

Answer (score 7):

This method returns the saved `id`

```
myobject = repository.saveAndFlush(myobject);
```

Now you have your `id`.

Answer (score 6):

Try specifying strategy for `@GeneratedValue` like

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Comment: AUTO is the default value: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Even though the save method is void, you can set a variable to it.(?)

```
    @PostMapping(value = "customer/{id}/wish/add")
public String processAddWish(Model model, @PathVariable int id,
                             @ModelAttribute @Valid WishOrder newWishOrder,
                             Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "customer/wish/add";
    }
    //Initialize variable to the save method, even though it is void and returns nothing//
    //Eliminates need to access object through a .findById//
    //If you need the id of the saved object instantly, just add .getId to save call//
    //wishOrderDao.save(newWishOrder).getId()//
    WishOrder wish = wishOrderDao.save(newWishOrder);
    Customer customer = customerDao.findById(id);
    customer.getWishList().add(wish);
    customerDao.save(customer);

    model.addAttribute("customer",(customer));
    model.addAttribute("wishList", (customer.getWishList()));

    return "customer/wishList";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't have a @Transactional annotation on your Service method.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers were able to solve this for me, but setting the below annotation worked.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
```

For context, I'm using mysql and have the ID set to the below definition

```
create table table_name(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  ... other columns ...
)
```