# Updating item created as part of @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, nhibernate, spring-data, persistence, spring-data-jpa

I'm having problems updating an object created as part of a set in a @OneToMany relationship.

Suppose I've got a very simple domain model, consisting of houses and people who live in those houses:

House:

```
@Entity
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Person> persons;

    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        persons.add(p);        

    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

}
```

Person:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private House house;

}
```

I've got a Spring Boot JPA repository for House, and a HouseService with the method:

```
@Transactional
public Person addPerson(Long houseId) {
    House house = houseRepository.findOne(houseId);
    Person person = new Person();
    house.addPerson(person);
    houseRepository.save(house);
    return person;
}
```

Calling the above method does create a new Person and persist that person in the database, but the returned Person instance doesn't have an ID set (i.e., addPerson().getId() returns null). Can I get the service to return a person instance that does have the ID of the persisted version?

I want to make changes to the Person created using the service's addPerson() method and be able to persist those changes at a later stage.

Comment: maybe you should have a bidirectonnal relation house can have person but person havn't house

Comment: Sorry I left that out of the code - there is a bidirectional relationship, I've updated the question to show this. Thanks.

Comment: with cascade too?

Comment: yep, cascade = CascadeType.ALL

Comment: add `mappedBy="house"` to your `@OneToMany`. Also i would define    `@JoinColumn(name = "ID_HOUSE")` one the `@ManyToOne` side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get id of Person you can create PersonRepository. Like in this [questshion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351156/spring-data-jpa-save-can-not-get-id).

```
person = personRepository.save(person);
personRepository.flush();
id=person.getId();
```

If you want to get person Id before persist, then you must generate id and manually set it.

Answer (score 0):

In any ORM framework, the persistence of the entity in db is governed by the ORM means there is no guarantee that the entity you called  for `houseRepository.save(house)` will be immediately persisted in database, in case you want such behaviour you have to force your JPA to flush the entity immediately within transaction scope.

For this you will have modify your `houseRepository.save` method to add the below logic after it calls the `entityManager.persist()`

Try adding the below code there

```
entityManager.flush();
```

I believe Spring boot JPA facilitates flush operation in it, in that case you can directly call it
`houseRepository.flush()` after your persist call.

Comment: seen save instead of persist but doesn't know the differences. thanks.