# Cannot save a user to H2: Id is not generated with GenerationType.AUTO

Tags: jpa, model-view-controller, spring-boot, thymeleaf, h2

By some reason the ID for my new user is not generated.

```
userRepository.save(user); //id = null and i can't create user
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/createuser")
public String creatingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "createuser";
}

@PostMapping("/createuser")
public String creatingSubmit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    userRepository.save(user); 
    return "login";
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private Integer id;
```

Log from the console:

```
User{id=null, email='example data', password='example data', name='example data', surname='example data', country='example data'}
```

[github link](https://github.com/dominikzaq/webapp-project)

Comment: What DBMS is used?

Comment: embeded database h2

Comment: `@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)` why do you need this annotation on Id? PK is not nullable and unique by default

Comment: With this annotation (@Column (nullable = false, unique = true)) and without it, id = null, I do not know why this is wrong

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351156/spring-data-jpa-save-can-not-get-id

Comment: The issue seems to be that a new object is created with the ID after you call `save()`