# Spring Hibernate JPA changes are not reflected immediately(Same call)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
userRepository.saveAndFlush(new User("arpi", new Date(1992, 10, 9), null));
accountRepository.saveAndFlush(new Account(userRepository.findAll().get(0), 199));
List<Account> accounts = userRepository.findAll().get(0).getAccounts(); //null but in db it exists
```

The accounts is empty even though in DB the account is created and relations are correct. Also if i close this request and make new request the accounts appear. So if i am saving and reading immediately its empty why? Also tried with save instead of saveAndFlush same result.

Why is this error? Is it because the response from DB is cached?
If yes how to fetch the user with account immediately post save in same request? 
Even save saves to DB immediately so whats difference between save and saveAndFlush?

Thanks for any clarity if provided.

Account and user entity

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class Account {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
private double balance;

public Account(User user, double balance) {
    this.user = user;
    this.balance = balance;
}

public Account(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
}
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String name;
private Date dob;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
List<Account> accounts;

public void addAccount(Account account) {
    this.accounts.add(account);
}

public User(String s, Date date, List<Account> account) {
    this.name = s;
    this.dob = date;
    this.accounts = account;
}
}
```

Call

```
userRepository.saveAndFlush(new User("arpi", new Date(1992, 10, 9), null));
accountRepository.saveAndFlush(new Account(userRepository.findAll().get(0), 199));
//        userRepository.save(new User("arpi", new Date(1992, 10, 9), null));
//        accountRepository.save(new Account(userRepository.findAll().get(0), 199));
//        accountRepository.flush();
//        userRepository.flush();
    List<Account> s = userRepository.findAll().get(0).getAccounts();
// s is null
```

Comment: Is your method or class marked with @Transactional?

Comment: no, its not marked as @Transactional

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351156/spring-data-jpa-save-can-not-get-id

Comment: Not similar but i tried all the suggestions, I am able to fetch by id but not on oneToMany relations

Comment: Maybe `userRepository.findAll().get(0)` returns you another User record which has no accounts.

Comment: No users table has a single entry. which i am creating in first line

Comment: Please add your User and Account Entity

Comment: @MyTwoCents have added additional details

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your entity User have the @OneToMany annotation in the field accounts as fetch lazy, if so you have to set it as eager

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Account> accounts;
```

Comment: No, its fetch eager, have added additional details above

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your entity mapping.

So basically what you want is Bidirectional mapping between `Account` and `User` as you have added `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany`.

If so there will be one Owner and one reference side.

`@JoinColumn` is used for Owner side and `@mappedBy`  on reference side

You have `@JoinColumn` on both entity.

Your mapping should be something like this

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    private double balance;

    ...
}

public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private Date dob;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    public void addAccount(Account account) {
        this.accounts.add(account);
    }

    public User(String s, Date date) {
        this.name = s;
        this.dob = date;
    }

}
```

This is the optimal solution

Refere [here for more detail](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Also I see some issue in these lines as well

```
userRepository.saveAndFlush(new User("arpi", new Date(1992, 10, 9), null));
```

Created a User with no link to Account.

```
accountRepository.saveAndFlush(new Account(userRepository.findAll().get(0), 199));
```

Created a Account with link to user.

```
List<Account> s = userRepository.findAll().get(0).getAccounts();
```

Now you want account from User which will be null as there is no reference from User to Account.

Try changing your code to this and try.  Please change the constructors in User entity as given above.

```
User user = new User("arpi", new Date(1992, 10, 9))
user.addAccount(new Account(199)):
userRepository.saveAndFlush();
List<Account> s = userRepository.findAll().get(0).getAccounts();
```

Comment: When i save through the user entity it works, my doubt is when i save them separately  with there own repository and try to fetch in the same rest call, Also my older implementation with join column on both sides works when i call the same api again, Its like more to do with cache of the entity i feel, but i can see the sql getting printed to fetch it again
Btw the changes you provided works but i was just experimenting with few more things

Answer (score 0):

I had to autowire the entitymanager and detach the object, as it was belonged to same session so it was not refreshing. It was triggering the queries though which is still strange